# Java Apache poi: Word - Unable to extract specific texts from document along with numbering and tables

Tags: java, apache-poi

Unable to extract specific texts from document along with numbering and tables.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set with the position to replace only the text with format

```
r.setText(text, 0);
```

For Table u need to find this way

```
    for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
     for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
      for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
         .....
        }}
        // Replace values with nested table 
        for (XWPFTable tbl2 : cell.getTables()) {
         for (XWPFTableRow row2 : tbl2.getRows()){
          for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
           for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
            ...
          }}
        }}}
```

Comment: Thanks Harsha, the solution provided above did not resolve my issue as I am still stuck with the same results.

Comment: It did work to me.. okay you can refer to the examples from this link: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/

Comment: Thanks, I did not work, the result is same as shown above in the picture. I did something different and I was able to retrieve numbering along with format, however when I try to do the same with another document that contains different numbering styles (upper letter numbering, lower letter numbering) I am just able to get decimal list numbering. I am not able to extract the data and keep same numbering styles.